# Isolated thermistor measurement

Tags: sensor, opto-isolator, high-voltage, protection, thermistor

I'm considering re-implementing my thermistor measurement circuit to be isolated, since it's destined for an industrial environment. The thermistor is a simple passive sensor and is not grounded on the far end.

U1 is a 5V/5V regulator rated for 3kV isolation. The line out to the thermistor is connected to protection shottkys, a TVS zener, and caps that set the time constant at (I think) ~1s.

U3 is a "linearized" optoisolator rated to 3.75kV isolation.

Back-of-the-envelope calculations for the following nominal values:

- the input and output of U2 at 2.5V,
- the LED current at 8.7mA,
- Irm1 = Irm2 = 90uA,
- line time constant = 853ms

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9PEOS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Questions:

- Have I made any mistakes in how the circuit is connected or the passives are chosen?
- Is it even necessary for this isolation to be done, given that the far end does not have its own ground?
- Are there any rules I should follow with regard to PCB layout (especially shuffling around the diodes and caps, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thermistors are relatively high level devices and are not generally grounded so it's not usually necessary to isolate them. You can add a low pass filter and use shielded wire to the thermistor if you expect significant EMI.

You should check the reverse leakage of those Schottky diodes- if they are the type I think I see-- at -4V and 75 degrees C they will typically leak 200uA!

---

Edit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7gt92.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The shottkys are SB140TA. Based on the specsheet, for 75C and even slight reverse bias, the leakage looks closer to 300uA :(

Comment: You might be able to get away with a BAT54, but I would add series resistance so the diodes don't have to work as hard and consider using a BAV99 with a bit more series resistance on the other side. It's better to have some series resistance to drop voltage than to try to shunt all the current away.

Comment: In terms of order away from the thermistor, would it go: R, diodes, C? Something small like 100 ohm? Since the resistance is critical to measurement, I'd have to account for it when calculating the temperature.

Comment: You can add a lot of resistance in series with the non-inverting input without it affecting anything significantly. I'll add a quick schematic above.

Comment: Ah, I found the BAV99 - it's actually an array of 2.

Comment: @Reinderien So is the BAT54, BTW.

Comment: BAV199 has Rc 5nA @25C@Vr75 and RC 80nA@150C@Vr75